# Сериализация JSON

Tags: json, javascript

Есть прототип объекта :

```
function Obj(n,m) {
  this.name = n;
  this.m = m;
}
var object = new Obj(1,2);
```

`JSON.stringify(object)` в Хроме выдает что-то типа "не могу обработать циклический объект", в Mozille же все работает. Если объект создан в единственном экземпляре :

```
var obj = {
  'name' : 'a'
},
```

то `JSON.stringify(object)` работает и в Хроме. Как с этим бороться? В чем дело? Подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант [сработал](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/BVVsk/) у меня и в FireFox и в Chrome.

Может, Ваш Хром решил, что некорректно использовать одинаковое имя для свойства и параметра. Попробуйте назвать их по-разному:

```
function Obj( n, m) {
  this.name = n;
  this._m = m;
}
var object = new Obj( 1,2);
alert( JSON.stringify( object));
```

Comment: Действительно работает. Спасибо за советик. Необходимо быть более внимательным к синтаксису

Comment: Кстати, ничего некорректного в одинаковых именах нет. Это даже более удобочитаемо и удобовоспринимаемо.

Comment: Корректно-некорректно решать не нам, а компилятору/интерпретатору.
А вообще, согласен, немного странно.

Comment: Для компилятора/интерпретатора name.m, m, obj.m в одной программе - это абсолютно разные сущности.

Comment: Всё верно: конфликта имён быть не должно. Но ошибка, которую вы упоминули, про «циклический объект», как раз возникает когда предлагают JSON'у сериализировать объект со ссылками на самого себя, или собственные переменные. Вот [примеры циклических структур](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010357/define-cyclic-data-structures). Может, Хром был старый, с какой-то необычной версией JS движка?

Comment: Да, запустил маленький код (см.выше) - уже работает в Хроме. А код где использовался ajax, который не работал нужно воссоздать и перепроверить. Но я точно помню, что в Мозилле работал,а в Хроме нет. И Хром абсолютно новый.